# How to get an F and p-value when doing a mixed model analysis in R

Tags: lme4-nlme

I'm not that good at R, but I'm trying to learn it myself while writing my bachelor thesis.

What I'm trying to do, is see if the interaction of delirium (2 levels, delirium or not) and eyes (2 levels, open or closed) has a significant effect on the relative power density of certain brainwaves. What I've seen in tutorials is that they create a model:

> rpd_eeg1_delta.model = lmer(rpd_eeg1_delta ~ Delirium*Eyes + (1+Delirium+Eyes|Subject) + (1+Delirium+Eyes|Measurement), data=dataset, REML=FALSE)

and compare this to the null model without the interaction using an anova

> rpd_eeg1_delta.null = lmer(rpd_eeg1_delta ~ Delirium + Eyes + (1+Delirium+Eyes|Subject) + (1+Delirium+Eyes|Measurement), data=dataset, REML=FALSE)
>   anova(rpd_eeg1_delta.model,rpd_eeg1_delta.null)

What I don't get is why this gives you a chi square and a p-value instead of a F and a p-value, while doing the same mixed model analysis in SPSS does give you a F and a p-value. I hope someone sees what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go into more detail about what you're not understanding. If you're question is more "how to do an f-test in R", then please refer to the manual or the tutorials.

Comment: @cherub Thank you for responding, I've edited my question, I hope it's clearer now